# Batch File Open pwd and user Ms Access .mdb Database

Tags: batch-file, ms-access, passwords

I have a Ms Access database I want to open from an option in my .bat file and cant figure it out.

Right now I have:

```
Start C:\SomeFolder\MyDBName.mdb /user MyUserName/pwd MyPassword
```

Also, I have another problem. I have a program that is open all the time and if its open on the desktop then the MyDBName.mdb will not open but if the program is closed then the MyDBName.mdb will open, why is that?

Comment: **(1)** In your batch command, are you actually missing the space before `/pwd`? **(2)** If the "other program" is opening the .mdb file as Exclusive can you make it stop doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type start /? from the command prompt you'll see that the first parameter is "title"

Change your start line to

```
    Start "" C:\SomeFolder\MyDBName.mdb /user MyUserName /pwd MyPassword
```

and it should work.

As Gord mentioned, the program in question probably has exclusive access to the database. You can use taskkill to close that program first by inserting the line

```
    taskkill /IM [Your program name.exe]
```

Before the start line.

Comment: The other program can not be killed it has to run minimized in background. Whats weired is if I go streight to the MS access database and open it it opens but if I use a batch file it never opens. Any thoughts? I will post back on the password and user in a few min when Im able to try it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I tried the Start "ABCproduct" C:\ABC\ABCproduct.mdb /user Test /pwd Admin and had to close the other program for it to open and it went to the screen that asked for password and User name and stoped and didnt enter either into the text fields. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you just type C:\ABC\ABCproduct.mdb /user Test /pwd Admin from the run line?

Comment: Ok, I tried C:\ABC\ABCproduct.mdb /user Test /pwd Admin in a CMD window two ways. First, with the other program open and it gave me "process can not access the file because its being used by another process". Second, with the other program closed and it opened the database but still showed the enter user name and password box with me having to enter both of them.

Comment: What version of Access are you using and what type of security is on the database?